# While foreach echo's twice?

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

just getting to grips with handling foreach loops. For each row, I am setting 'vine' and 'mp4' in $array however when I echo those values they post twice. Here's my code:

```
$sql="SELECT vine_id,mp4_url FROM videos LIMIT 1";

$res=mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    foreach ($row as $array) {
        $array=array(
            "vine"=>$row['vine_id'],
            "mp4"=>$row['mp4_url']);
            echo $array["vine"];
            echo $array["mp4"];
     }
}
```

Here's my output:

```
bUjdjmFHt5I //vine
https://vines.s3.amazonaws.com/v/videos/2013/04/20/A42066A1-EC83-4211-BA20-DAD287C8AF1E-362-0000002797BBAC52_1.0.7.mp4?versionId=oMGICGs2c7dCbodVIHHiaQ1MhqKg65.y //mp4

bUjdjmFHt5I //vine
https://vines.s3.amazonaws.com/v/videos/2013/04/20/A42066A1-EC83-4211-BA20-DAD287C8AF1E-362-0000002797BBAC52_1.0.7.mp4?versionId=oMGICGs2c7dCbodVIHHiaQ1MhqKg65.y //mp4
```

Am I missing something in my code that's making this post twice?

Comment: The foreach loop is redundant, it's looping over every COLUMN in the returned row, but you don't need to do this based on your code. Just use the while loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are looping over an array that gets instantly destroyed in your code:

```
$sql="SELECT vine_id,mp4_url FROM videos LIMIT 1";

$res=mysql_query($sql);
```

Assuming everything went well, you start with $res pointing to a mysql resource that will deliver exactly one result set.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
```

You are fetching this result set. $row is now an array with the two keys vine_id and mp4_url.

```
    foreach ($row as $array) {
```

Now you are assigning the two keys values to $array, one after another. You have two keys, this loop will run two times.

```
        $array=array(
            "vine"=>$row['vine_id'],
            "mp4"=>$row['mp4_url']);
```

Now you destroy the value that gets assigned by foreach and overwrite it with values from $row.

You really only create a copy of the array with slightly different key names.

```
        echo $array["vine"];
        echo $array["mp4"];
```

The loop runs twice, the echo occurs twice with the same content.

```
     }
}
```

What you really want:

```
// Use alias in SQL to get the array keys you want
$sql="SELECT vine_id as vine, mp4_url as mp4 FROM videos LIMIT 1";

$res=mysql_query($sql);

// assign the SQL result to a variable of your choice.
while($array=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    // No need to copy the array
    echo $array["vine"];
    echo $array["mp4"];
}
```

Comment: Superb answer, thank you Sven. Really helps those getting to grips with loops etc.

Answer (score 7):

You're looping twice. Try this:

```
$sql="SELECT vine_id,mp4_url FROM videos LIMIT 1";

$res=mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $array = array(
        "vine" => $row['vine_id'],
        "mp4" => $row['mp4_url'],
    );
    echo $array["vine"];
    echo $array["mp4"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you antony, didn't register that while is intact a loop itself. Thanks, will accept your answer in 10~